# Print Local Storage onto page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

How can I show the users high score in my game? I can't use `onload()`, so how can I show the stored high scores? Here is my code to get scores.

```
var hs = localStorage["hs"];

function myFunction() {
    $("#demo").text(hs);
}
```

Comment: 1. Why can't you use `onload`? 2. **When** do you need to show the scores?

Comment: @nem: One possible reason for not being able to use `onload` is that it is already being used by another piece of code. An inferior, but valid workaround is to chain `onload` handlers; the better way is to use `addEventListener`, as multiple listeners can listen to the same event (and do not interfere with `onload`). That said, OP, you provided no info on what is going wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="showscore"></div>
        // Keep the script tag at the end of your HTML code.
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //localStorage.setItem("highScore","564544");
            var highScore = localStorage.getItem("highScore"); 
            // Considering you already have highScore set in local storage.
            // Uncomment your line number 10 if you want to set in local storage
            if(highScore){
                document.getElementById('showscore').innerHTML = highScore;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('showscore').innerHTML = "Play your first game";            
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can use innerHTML dom attribute here to insert your highscore stored in local storage.

Make sure you insert the script at the end of html code, as the script needs the all elements to be rendered first.

Comment: You have to provide an explanation for your code example.

Comment: im so stupid... thank you @Abhishek Jain for helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    localStorage.setItem("highscore","100");
    var v=localStorage.getItem("highscore");
    alert(v);
</script>
```

you need to use setItem() for assigning value to the variable and getItem() for fetching the value